# python matplotlib plot datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a simple line graph based on a datetime index. But I get an error message.

```
#standard packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#visualization
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#create weekly datetime index
edf = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\j~\raw.csv', parse_dates=[6])
edf2 = edf[['DATESENT','Sales','Traffic']].copy()
edf2['DATESENT']=pd.to_datetime(edf2['DATESENT'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
edf2 = edf2.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(edf2['DATESENT']))
edf2.resample('w').sum()
edf2

#output

            SALES
DATESENT     
2014-01-05  476
2014-01-12  67876
```

Then I try to plot (the simplest line plot possible to see sales by week)

```
#linegraph
edf3.plot(x='DATESENT',y='Sales')
```

But I get this error message

> KeyError: 'DATESENT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `KeyError` because your `'DATESENT'` is the index and NOT a column in `edf3`. You can do this instead:

```
#linegraph
edf3.plot(x=edf3.index,y='Sales')
```